# Поэлементный вывод списка на экран

Tags: haskell

Хотелось бы понять, можно ли в Haskell каким-то образом вывести список на экран поэлементно, то бишь аналог такого кода на Java

```
for(String s: string_array){
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

---

Почитал книжки - нашел следующее решение:

```
printList list = case list of
    [] -> putStrLn ""
    (x:xs) -> do
        putStrLn $ show x
        printList xs
```

Answer (score 8):

Поэтапное улучшение ("ухаскеление") решения:

0. Добавляется сигнатура

```
printList :: [String] -> IO ()
printList list = case list of
    [] -> putStrLn ""
    (x:xs) -> do
        putStrLn $ show x
        printList xs
```

1. Исчезает case:

```
printList :: [String] -> IO ()
printList [] = putStrLn ""
printList (x:xs) = do
    putStrLn $ show x
    printList xs
```

2. Исчезает do:

```
printList :: [String] -> IO ()
printList [] = putStrLn ""
printList (x:xs) = (putStrLn $ show x) >> printList xs
```

3. Исчезает явная рекурсия (правда, пустая строка в конце тоже исчезает):

```
printList :: [String] -> IO ()
printList = mapM_ $ putStrLn . show
```

4. Обобщение со строк на любые объекты, к которым можно применить `show`:

```
printList :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
printList = mapM_ $ putStrLn . show
```

5. Выражение `putStrLn . show` эквивалентно функции `print`

```
printList :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
printList = mapM_ print
```

Если кому-нибудь интересно, могу разбить пункт "3." на более мелкие шаги.

Answer (score 2):

Можно ещё вот так, если у вас список строк

```
printList::[String]->IO ()
printList = putStrLn.unlines
```

или вот так для произвольного типа реализующего Show

```
printList::Show a => [a] -> IO ()
printList = putStrLn.unlines.map show
```

Answer (score 0):

Буквальный перевод приведённого ява-кода, два варианта:

```
mapM_ print [1,2,3,4]
forM_ [1,2,3,4] print
```